# share CSS variable var() to :global() svelte parent component reactivelly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svelte

I tried to put the minimal example: (not real code, but similar and simpler to demonstrate the problem)

```html
<script>
let parentOverflow = false;

function setParentOverflow() {
  if(parentOverflow) return 'hidden'
  return 'auto'
}
</script>

<div 
  style="--parent-overflow:{setParentOverflow()}"
  transition:scale={{duration: 2000}}
  on:introstart={() => (parentOverflow = true)}
  on:introend={() => (parentOverflow = false)}
> 
  hello world
</div>

<style>
  :global(.parent) {
    overflow: var(--parent-overflow);
  }
</style>
```

As you see I am using `:global()` in the style tag,

which means you can style globally also the parent div

---

everything work fine in all the code (functions, styles, transitions, introstart, introend)

❌ but `overflow: var(--parent-overflow)` give me the problem

technically in dev tools is shown (so the parent have the style, see image below)

[image]

but the the parent can't have the `var()`, yes, because ✅ if I write `overflow: hidden` work very good.

but `var()` not.

---

is there a way to pass also `var()` the value reactively to the parent?

---

another info is that if a child works fine the `var()`

---

I can't move the code function to the parent since the animation happens on the child.

but I can pass/export in some way a prop if there is a way for the parent and then write the CSS there.

I am open to everything that can make pass the returned value of the function to the parent and then style the parent reactively from child var.

---

also if the class `.parent` is present to multiple is there a way to only change the parent one of the child, and not all `.parent`?

```html
<parent> <!-- yes only this --> 
  <child>
<parent>

<parent> <!-- don't change this -->

<parent> <!-- the child style on the first don't need to change this, because they are totally different things --> 
  <child>
<parent>
```

> basically a concept like this `.closest()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest?retiredLocale=it (but without javascript, only css :global())
>
> to mention .closest() can't work correctly in svelte so isn't worth it.  I think can be a way with only CSS only (or svelte magic)

---

sorry for the long details, but I tried to put everything I know.

If you more details tell me I will add them too.

thanks for reading :)

Comment: Adding all the relevant details is a great practise, thank you!

I'd suggest asking your question about multiple `.parent` classes in a separate question, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Child and Parent component are connected via slot

```
<Parent>
    <Child />
</Parent>
```

you could use [`setContext / getContext`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-setcontext) for the communication. Like this only a Parent and it's Children share the information, the other sibling Parent components are not affected. A store is used so that the value is reactive. [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/e1b2871d23604b1d9424c14f8cd28e54?version=3.50.1)

###### Parent.svelte

```
<script>
    import {setContext} from 'svelte'
    import {writable} from 'svelte/store'
    const parentOverflow = writable('hidden')
    setContext('parentOverflow', parentOverflow)
</script>

<div class="parent" style:overflow={$parentOverflow}>
    <slot />
</div>
```

###### Child.svelte

```
<script>
    import {scale} from 'svelte/transition'
    import {getContext} from 'svelte'
    let parentOverflow = getContext('parentOverflow')
</script>

<div transition:scale="{{duration: 2000}}"
         on:introend="{() => ($parentOverflow = 'auto')}"
         > 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...
</div>
```

Comment: @stackdeveloper Yes, it's not accessible outside the parent, only *"...available to children of the component (including slotted content)"* (from the docs)